# Combining Count and MIN functions

Tags: sql, count, min

I have a part of my query as:

```
SUM(POReceiptQuantity)      as Receieved,
MIN(ItemLocalStandardCost)  as Low,
MAX(ItemLocalStandardCost)  as High,
```

Received returns the total number of Items we sold this year.  The LOW is the lowest price we paid, and High is the highest price we paid.

I'm trying to incorporate a new column showing how many if the item we sold at the Low price.  I tried to use Count along with Min function but it returns a "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

Does anyone have any ideas how i could go about this.

Thank you

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Answer (score 0):

You need create a subquery with your current `GROUP BY` query and join with your Original Table. Then you can use a conditional `COUNT`

```
 SELECT  T2.Received, 
         T2.Low,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN T1.ItemLocalStandardCost = T2.Low THEN 1 END) as Total_Low,
         T2.High,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN T1.ItemLocalStandardCost = T2.High THEN 1 END) as Total_High

 FROM YourTable T1
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM(Y.POReceiptQuantity)      as Receieved,
                     MIN(Y.ItemLocalStandardCost)  as Low,
                     MAX(Y.ItemLocalStandardCost)  as High
              FROM YourTable Y
              GROUP BY .... ) as T2
```